# Lost access to S3 after granting access to STS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have two different AWS accounts, `DEV` and `PROD`, and I would like to create a user in `DEV` to manage S3 buckets in both. I've created the user Bob, which has the following policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::some-dev-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::another-dev-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This actually works, Bob can list all the buckets and access some of them. In order to allow Bob accessing S3 buckets in the `PROD` account, I've created the `PROD-S3-Access` role there, with the appropriate permissions and a trust relationship that allows `DEV` users to assume it. Going back to `DEV`, I create a new policy that allows Bob assuming the role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::prod-account-id:role/PROD-S3-Access"
        }
    ]
}
```

This also works fine, Bob can now access `PROD`s S3. However, when doing an `aws s3 ls` in the `DEV` account, Bob gets this message `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`. Confusingly, if I detach the policy that lets Bob assuming `PROD-S3-Access`, he can read `DEV`'s S3 buckets again. Any clue?

EDIT:

The issue was actually caused by a condition I hadn't noticed, which required the user to have MFA enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merely adding an `ALLOW` policy to a user should not remove access. It is, indeed, strange.

**An alternative to assuming a role** is to give Bob in `DEV` permission to directly access the `PROD` buckets. This requires two things:

- **IAM permissions on DEV Bob** to access the PROD buckets
- A **Bucket Policy on each PROD Bucket** permitting access from DEV Bob

This way, the single user can access both DEV and PROD buckets, making it possible to copy data between them.